# setNeedsDisplay: Too long between redraw cycles

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm new to cocoa. I thought I could set the UITableViewCell background view to my own custom subclass in order to display a loading bar in the background of the cell, but it seems that calling `setNeedsDisplay` when I want to update the bar is not fast enough for my needs. Right now I'm updating it (by that I mean updating data in the UIView and then calling `setNeedsDisplay`) every .1 seconds and only seeing it actual update every 30-40 seconds. Is this normal? Is there any way to speed it up? If not are there other options for what I'm trying to do?

This is my code for draw rect (there's a helper methode above it) and `updateBarAt`, which is what is called to update it:

```
-(void) updateBarAt: (float) playHead {
    self.playHead = playHead;
    NSLog(@"%f", self.playHead);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void) drawBackground: (CGRect) rect{
    double totalTime = self.playFor + self.wait;

    double waitPercentage = self.wait / totalTime;
    double playForPercentage = (self.playFor - self.fadeIn - self.fadeOut) / totalTime;
    double fadeInPercentage = self.fadeIn / totalTime;
    double fadeOutPercentage = self.fadeOut / totalTime;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect blueRect = CGRectMake((waitPercentage+fadeInPercentage)*rect.size.width, 0, playForPercentage*rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, .639, .737, 1, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, blueRect);
    CGRect greenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, waitPercentage*rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, .843, 1, .651, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, greenRect);


    CGRect purpleRect = CGRectMake(waitPercentage*rect.size.width+.1, 0, fadeInPercentage*rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, .7451, .639, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, purpleRect);

    CGRect purpleR = CGRectMake((1.0 - fadeOutPercentage)*rect.size.width - .5, 0, fadeOutPercentage*rect.size.width + .5, rect.size.height);
    CGContextFillRect(context, purpleR);
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { //just does blue and green, need to add purple. Research
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);


    if (self.playHead == -1)
        return;
    [super drawRect:rect];

    double totalTime = self.playFor + self.wait;
    double playedPercentage = self.playHead / totalTime;

    double waitPercentage = self.wait / totalTime;
    double playForPercentage = (self.playFor - self.fadeIn - self.fadeOut) / totalTime;
    double fadeInPercentage = self.fadeIn / totalTime;
    double fadeOutPercentage = self.fadeOut / totalTime;

    NSLog(@"Played: %f Wait: %f Play: %f Fade In: %f Fade Out: %f", playedPercentage, waitPercentage, playForPercentage, fadeInPercentage, fadeOutPercentage);

    if (playedPercentage <= waitPercentage) {
        waitPercentage = playedPercentage;
        playForPercentage = 0;
        fadeInPercentage = 0;
        fadeOutPercentage = 0;
    } else if (playedPercentage <= waitPercentage+fadeInPercentage) {
        playForPercentage = 0;
        fadeInPercentage = playedPercentage - waitPercentage;
        fadeOutPercentage = 0;
    } else if (playedPercentage <= waitPercentage+fadeInPercentage + playForPercentage) {
        playForPercentage = playedPercentage - waitPercentage - fadeInPercentage;
        fadeOutPercentage = 0;
    } else {
        fadeOutPercentage = playedPercentage - waitPercentage - playForPercentage;
    }

    //[self drawBackground:rect];

    CGRect blueRect = CGRectMake((waitPercentage+fadeInPercentage)*rect.size.width, 0, playForPercentage*rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, blueRect);

    CGRect greenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, waitPercentage*rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, greenRect);


    CGRect purpleRect = CGRectMake(waitPercentage*rect.size.width+.1, 0, fadeInPercentage*rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.33, 0.1, .55, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, purpleRect);

    CGRect purpleR = CGRectMake((1.0 - fadeOutPercentage)*rect.size.width - .5, 0, fadeOutPercentage*rect.size.width + .5, rect.size.height);
    CGContextFillRect(context, purpleR);
}
```

Comment: How do you call `updateBarAt:`? Are you sure it is called on the main thread?

Comment: @rmaddy Actually it's called on a separate queue, i'm guessing that's a bad thing.... Sorry, I'm really new to cocoa

Comment: @rmaddy I know that it's being called on time, if that's what you mean...

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your `updateBarAt:` method. Then run the app with the debugger. When you reach the breakpoint, see which thread you are in. If it is not the main thread (thread 0), then that is your issue. You must ensure that the call to `setNeedsDisplay` is done on the main thread. You post the code that calls `updateBarAt:`.

Comment: @rmaddy if I'm not on the main thread, can I just send a "dispatch_get_main_queue" (I think that's it) to get it back on the main thread?

Comment: Exactly. Use `dispatch_async` with `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Comment: @rmaddy if you make that an answer, I'll check it off b/c it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most `UIKit` use needs to be done on the main thread. Most likely your `updateBarAt:` method isn't being called on the main thread which means your call to `setNeedsDisplay` is being done on some background thread.

One possible solution would be this:

```
- (void)updateBarAt:(float)playHead {
    self.playHead = playHead;
    NSLog(@"%f", self.playHead);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    });
}
```

Another option would be to wrap the call to `updateBarAt:` in the `dispatch_async` call.